# Moving the svn repository along with trac from one server to another

Tags: svn, trac, data-migration

I inherited the svn repository along with trac system. They were held on Ubuntu. The authorisation was held by subversion.

I have to make them run under VisualSVN with Windows authentication. What steps I should take to move them slightly and without major problems?

I'd like to keep:

- svn repo and trac association
- users definied under Linux system

Comment: You are better of asking this as http://serverfault.com, but svn has a dump & load facility, and an evil, non-reliable, way to port users is just copying the `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/group` files. Dunno about Trac ;)

Comment: Never mind copying those files, migrating to Windows I see now...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `svnadmin dump`

> Subversion provides such functionality by way of repository dump
>   streams. A repository dump stream (often referred to as a “dump file”
>   when stored as a file on disk) is a portable, flat file format that
>   describes the various revisions in your repository—what was changed,
>   by whom, when, and so on. This dump stream is the primary mechanism
>   used to marshal versioned history—in whole or in part, with or without
>   modification—between repositories. And Subversion provides the tools
>   necessary for creating and loading these dump streams: the svnadmin
>   dump and svnadmin load subcommands, respectively, and the svnrdump
>   program.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate

And for Trac, you'd better have to use sqlite (or it gets trickier) and `trac-admin` would do it.

> Note: Automatic backup of environments that don't use SQLite as
>   database backend is not supported at this time. As a workaround, we
>   recommend that you stop the server, copy the environment directory,
>   and make a backup of the database using whatever mechanism is provided
>   by the database system.

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracBackup